# Only 1 out of 3 PayPal smart buttons showed on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I have tried to put 3 different PayPal smart buttons on webpage, but only one renders (is shown). I've tried changing div id (as you can see in to code), but the problem is still there. As you can see each button should be in one td tag, but only one is shown on page.
Here is the code for all 3 buttons.

```
 <td><div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AW70d1H_PLPMaT_7BK_kSGImw6w9DHpP2qHE3i6htPNCCOS9_dhVG52H3ITkdTWppulwYVC1NrMjgBaz&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'blue',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',

      },
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                      value: '3.60'
                  }
              }],application_context: {
        shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
      }
          });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              location.href = 'PayPal/premium_1.php';
          });
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
</td>

     <td><div id="paypal-button-container2"></div>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AW70d1H_PLPMaT_7BK_kSGImw6w9DHpP2qHE3i6htPNCCOS9_dhVG52H3ITkdTWppulwYVC1NrMjgBaz&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
      paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
              shape: 'pill',
              color: 'blue',
              layout: 'vertical',
              label: 'paypal',

          },
          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.create({
                  purchase_units: [{
                      amount: {
                          value: '15.12'
                      }
                  }],application_context: {
            shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
          }
              });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                  location.href = 'PayPal/premium_6.php';
              });
          }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container2');
    </script>
    </td>
     <td><div id="paypal-button-container3"></div>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AW70d1H_PLPMaT_7BK_kSGImw6w9DHpP2qHE3i6htPNCCOS9_dhVG52H3ITkdTWppulwYVC1NrMjgBaz&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
      paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
              shape: 'pill',
              color: 'blue',
              layout: 'vertical',
              label: 'paypal',

          },
          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.create({
                  purchase_units: [{
                      amount: {
                          value: '22.92'
                      }
                  }],application_context: {
            shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
          }
              });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                  location.href = 'PayPal/premium_12.php';
              });
          }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container3');
    </script>
    </td>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only load the SDK script once per page.